# RestSharp json request is not working

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I want to make a request to HackerEarth api v3 to run some code using c#.

I tried with `httpwebrequest` and `webclient` but i keep getting this error:

```
Forbidden 403 error
```

So i switched to restsharp and now i get another error:

```
ArgumentMissingError: client_secret is needed!
```

I'm trying to make a json request with the code below, but as you can see it doesn't work.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://api.hackerearth.com/v3/code/run/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

var postdata = new
{
    client_secret = "***",
    async = "0",
    source = "print 'Hello World'",
    time_limit = "5",
    memory_limit = "262144"
};
var json = request.JsonSerializer.Serialize(postdata);

request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content;

Console.WriteLine(content);
```

I also tried unsing ironPython to make it like they do it but there are some problems with the libriries and it's kind of hard to combine asp.net mvc with ironPython.

What is the correct way to make a json request using restsharp?

Comment: It's the same error for both of them. It's just with the RestSharp client you're getting the error body automatically. You were getting a 403 Forbidden response with the HTTPWebRequest but you weren't reading the body. The documentation clearly states that that error corresponds to a 403 response code.

Comment: Also, you're serializing the object as json, but the [python documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) seems to suggest that `requests.post` will, by default, post using form encoding. This is what's used in HackerEarth's API documents.

Comment: so i should add the values with request.AddParameter() ?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm unfamiliar with RestSharp and with HackerEarth - I was just trying to find some information that may help :)

Comment: i tried it and it worked first time, same was with the httprequest, second time when i ran it didn't worked anymore